# how to open files in vscode from integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, ide

Is there a way to open files in the current vscode text editor window from the integrated terminal, or do I always have to use the file browser on the side?  This would be really helpful for opening occasional files that don't really need to be part of my current workspace.  Additionally if this allowed me to edit files as sudo that would be awesome.

Comment: See opening files and folders from the command line: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-files-and-folders

Answer (score 2):

You can open the directory you are in by typing `code .` or a specific directory by using `code <dir name>` and you can open files with the same thing `code <file name>` you can even open multiple files eg. `code inde.html style.css`

Hope that answers the question

Comment: That's close, but it opens a new window, which I guess I can live with.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `STRG + P` to open another file.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/editingevolved#_quick-file-navigation